# Reading all content of a Java BufferedReader including the line termination characters

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm writing a TCP client that receives some binary data and sends it to a device. The problem arises when I use BufferedReader to read what it has received.

I'm extremely puzzled by finding out that there is no method available to read all the data. The `readLine()` method that everybody is using, detects both `\n` and `\r` characters as line termination characters, so I can't get the data and concat the lines, because I don't know which char was the line terminator. I also can't use `read(buf, offset, num)`, because it doesn't return the number of bytes it has read. If I read it byte by byte using `read()` method, it would become terribly slow. Please someone tell me what is the solution, this API seems quite stupid to me!

---

Well, first of all thanks to everyone. I think the main problem was because I had read tutorialspoint instead of Java documentation. But pardon me for it, as I live in Iran, and Oracle doesn't let us access the documentation for whatever reason it is. Thanks anyway for the patient and helpful responses.

Comment: I ended up writing my own Reader/Writer thread.

Comment: But read(buf, offset, num) does return number of characters read: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read(char[],%20int,%20int)  
Once you read the line, you can create a String from this and then concatenate however you want.

Comment: This is what I read in tutorialspoint:

Comment: Return Value

The method returns a character as an integer. If the end of the stream has been reached the method returns -1.

Comment: Err... "binary data" and "Reader"? Just because of those two expressions in the same question, the problem is obvious: you are doing it wrong. Binary data is not text. So, what is it that you _really_ want to do?

Comment: @Arash You should be reading the official Javadoc. You can't cite any old arbitrary Internet junk.

Comment: The downvote was mine, and it was because you uttered the remark 'this API seems quite stupid to me' after failing to check your assumptions with the standard reference. You can't seriously assert that an API that's been in use for nearly twenty years can really have the shortcomings you describe. Your claim about Oracle denying you access to the Javadoc is equally incredible.

Comment: I'm asking a question. And I said "seems quite stupid to me", and I also had said that I was "extremely puzzled". I don't think I offended anyone in that sentence, and I don't understand your anger. And why is my "claim" about oracle incredible? I would be thankful if you explain it to me!

Comment: FYI when I click on the link above, all that I see is a redirection to this http://www.oracle.com/splash/rpls/embargoed.html#read%28char[],%20int,%20int%29

Comment: @EJP I didn't offend anyone in my question, I just asked a question. But you are talking like I'm lying here. I think you need a little patience and thinking before talking like this. After all, stackoverflow.com is to let people help each other. If you don't get this, I think you are in the wrong community. This is not a place for trashing each other. If I say I'm facing a restricted access in oracle website and java documentation, it is a fact, and I don't get why do you think I'm lying. Please think before judging others.

Comment: OK, can you please settle down? Since my answer has been accepted, the core of the problem seems to be what I surmise, that is a core misunderstanding about how Java handles binary and text streams to start with. I do not believe there is an incentive to poison one another further at this point... Although I surmise that a SO wiki entry for Java's handling of binary vs text may be in order :p

Comment: I took the trouble to look up the tutorialspoint material. It doesn't say that the read() method doesn't return the number of bytes read. It does say it returns an `int`. Your question is chock full of invalid and unchecked assumptions.

Comment: @EJP here is the link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedreader_read_char_len.htm . Man you really should have some anger management sessions.

Comment: @fge Thanks for the answer. I feel offended here, but I totally agree with you.

Comment: @EJP I believe the core of the problem here, as I mention in my answer, is not about tutorialspoint or whatever; the core of the problem stems in the fact that a "binary stream" and a "text stream" are fundamentally different. I didn't even read the tutorialspoint link: how I came to understand the difference is due to my personal experience in dealing with such problems and it happens that I could spot the problem immediately due to the way the question was asked. But that is no reason to downvote the question, imho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more than likely an XY problem.

The beginning of your question reads:

> I'm writing a TCP client that receives some **binary data** and sends it to a device. The problem arises when **I use BufferedReader** to read what it has received.

This is binary data; **do not use a `Reader` to start with!** A Reader wraps an InputStream using a Charset and yields a stream of `char`s, not `byte`s. See, among other sources, [here](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1k-JM1yQUnOat7VtCe47yRu3_dMceReaAtppoW0Eyh-4/edit?usp=sharing) for more details.

Next:

> I'm extremely puzzled by finding out that there is no method available to read all the data

With reason. There is no telling how large the data may be, and as a result such a method would be fraught with problems if the data you receive is too large.

So, now that using a `Reader` is out of the way, what you really need to do is this:

- read some binary data from a `Socket`;
- copy this data to another source.

The solutions to do that are many; here is one solution which requires nothing but the standard JDK (7+):

```
final byte[] buf = new byte[8192]; // or other

try (
    final InputStream in = theSocket.getInputStream();
    final OutputStream out = whatever();
) {
    int nrBytes;
    while ((nrBytes = in.read(buf)) != -1)
        out.write(buf, 0, nrBytes);
}
```

Wrap this code in a method or whatever etc.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm extremely puzzled by finding out that there is no method available to read all the data.

There are three.

> The readLine() method that everybody is using, detects both \n and \r characters as line termination characters, so I can't get the data and concat the lines, because I don't know which char was the line terminator.

Correct. It is documented to suppress the line terminator.

> I also can't use read(buf, offset, num), because it doesn't return the number of bytes it has read.

It returns the number of *chars* read.

> If I read it byte by byte using read() method, it would become terribly slow.

That reads it char by char, not byte by byte, but you're wrong about the performance. It's buffered.

> Please someone tell me what is the solution

You shouldn't be using a `Reader` for binary data in the first place. I can only suggest you re-read the Javadoc for:

```
BufferedInputStream.read() throws IOException;
BufferedInputStream.read(byte[]) throws IOException;
BufferedInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) throws IOException;
```

The last two both return the number of bytes read, or -1 at end of stream.

> this API seems quite stupid to me!

No comment.

Comment: Love the "No comment". Made my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place everyone who reads data has to plan for \n, \r, \r\n as possible sequences except when parsing HTTP headers which must be separated with  \r\n. You could easily read line by line and output whatever line separator you like.

Secondly the read method returns the number of characters it has read into a char[] so that works exactly correctly if you want to read a chunk of chars and do your own line parsing and outputting.

Answer (score -2):

The best thing I can recommended is that you use BufferedReader.read() and iterate over every character in the file. Something like this:

```
String filename = ...
br = new BufferedReader( new FileInputStream(filename));
while (true) {
   String l = "";
   Char c = " ";
   while (true){
        c = br.read();
        if not c == "\n"{
        // do stuff, not sure what you want with the endl encoding
        // break to return endl-free line
    }
    if not c == "\r"{
        // do stuff, not sure what you want with the endl encoding
        // break to return endl-free line
        Char ctwo = ' '
        ctwo = br.read();
        if ctwo == "\n"{
            // do extra stuff since you know that you've got a \r\n
        }
    }
    else{
        l = l + c;
    }
   if (l == null) break;
    ...
   l = "";
}
```

previously answered by @https://stackoverflow.com/users/615234/arrdem

Comment: No because the BufferedReader buffers behind the scenes.

Comment: Doesnt compile; uses `==` to compare Strings; compares chars to Strings; and doesn't address the several underlying fallacies in the question.